# Query results of Cassandra DB

Tags: javascript, java, html, cassandra, playframework-2.0

Im creating a Cassandra based web application: so far using Play Framework. Im connecting with Cassandra via Java Driver but how can I embed the query results to my frontend? 
Details: I have a Users column family and want to show ALL USERS on my page. 
Is there any option to embed query results in HTML or JavaScript? Or is there any other method common?

Thanks in advance and cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The typical approach is to serve your webpages from a server that can build them dynamically. An example for java would be serving pages which were originally jsp templates that were processed by your server (e.g. tomcat or glassfish) that were processed into html.

So something like this:

```
backend java queries cassandra (SELECT * FROM users)
  -> passes results to jsp
    -> jsp gets processed into html by server
      -> server sends html to user.
```

The web application which is used to demo cassandra is an example of how one might build a twitter clone using C*. [**This repo**](https://github.com/jhermes/twissjava) shows how you might use java and cassandra to serve webpages.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can I use that approach directly within Play Framework structures? Or is there any problem to use JSP within Play?

Comment: @Messy Yes, you just have to add a cassandra java driver to your dependencies (I recommend [datastax's driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) which is considered the industry standard right now). And then you can embed the queries in your java code.

Answer (score 1):

Play use "Twirl" as template engine. Of course you can change it to use any one you like. The simplest output still a plain text.

You use Play and Cassandra. Both of them are created for the asynchronous programming. So most efficient way would be to utilise this ability.

One more point - you are going to print all users, this means that result could be huge. Better way would be to print it by chunks, like video streaming, other way, result could be so huge that server memory could be not enough for few request in the same time.

I code a simple "one function" solution for easy understanding. Better to split it in real program.

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture;

public class Application extends Controller {

  public Result users(){
    // Cassandra connection information.
    String node = "localhost";
    int port = 9042;

    // Connect to the cassandra.
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
      .addContactPoint(node)
      .withPort(port)
      .build();
    Session session = cluster.connect();

    // Prepare output.
    Chunks<String> chunks = new StringChunks() {
            public void onReady(Chunks.Out<String> out) {

        // Query data from the cassandra.
        String query = "SELECT * FROM mykeyspace.users";

        // Do asynchronious query to the cassandra.
        ResultSetFuture resultSet = session.executeAsync(query);
        Futures.addCallback(resultSet,
          new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ResultSet set) {
              try {
                // This cycle asynchronious as well.
                // It will fetch some data, then process it, then fetch more
                // All this done by cassandra driver
                set.forEach(row -> {
                        // Just plain text. You can output JSON as well.
                        out.write(row.toString());
                        out.write("\n");
                });
              } finally {
                out.close();
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                out.write(sw.toString());
                out.close();
            }
          }, MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor());

            }
        };

    return ok(chunks);
  }
}
```